# RAILS: saving categories/subjects to user with checkboxes and categories table

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I want to make a table called `subject_types` and populate it with different subjects such as english, spanish, history. And assign the `subjects` table to each `user`. I want the user to be able to select multiple `subjects` with a checkbox and it will save those specific ones and keep checked. each user can save their own `preferences/services`. Im trying to figure out the best way to approach this.

here is how it would look
[image]

- in a way the user is editing their settings. I want to be able to take this information and use it later to find results with only those subject types that they select. is there a tutorial or similar reference to this?

-Should I make the `subject_types` model and populate with these subjects or is there a better approach?

**possible solution**

- could I have an array in a column in my user table? the array would be the ids of the `subjects` table. How can i do that??

Thank you

**Updated:**

```html
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %> 

  
<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:writing_type_ids, WritingType.all, :id, :name) %>
 
  <%= f.submit 'submit' %>
<% end %>
```

```rails
class WritingType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_writing_types
  has_many :users, through: :user_writing_types
end


class UserWritingType < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :writing_type
end


class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :user_writing_types
 has_many :writing_types, through: :user_writing_types
end
```

My migration for the join

```rails
create_table :user_writing_types do |t|
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
      t.belongs_to :writing_type, index: true
      t.boolean :active, default: false
      t.timestamps
    end
```

**latest update**

Im getting my last of errors! when i click submit on that page i get `No route matches [PATCH] "/users/51"`.

- I added this `<%= f.collection_check_boxes(:writing_type_ids, WritingType.all, :id, :name) %>` to my edit form in `devise` `edit.html.erb`.  The writing_type names populate on the checkboxes, but nothing gets submitted to the database on the `user_writing_type` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by creating a many to many relation with a join model by using [has_many :through associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_subjects
  has_many :subjects, through: :user_subjects
end

class Subject < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_subjects
  has_many :users, through: :user_subjects
end

# this is the join model
class UserSubject < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject
end
```

You can then create a check box to add subjects to a user with [`collection_checkboxes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes):

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.collection_checkboxes(:subject_ids, Subject.all, :id, :name) %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

> could I have an array in a column in my user table? the array would be
>   the ids of the subjects table. How can i do that??

You don't.

Even though Postgres for example allows you to create array type columns 
 it is not a good solution as thats not how associations work in ActiveRecord.

Its also a crappy relational database design as its messy to write queries with a join though an array column and it does not let you enforce referential integrity with foreign keys or have good indices for performance.

Comment: Im getting my last of errors! when i click submit i get `No route matches [PATCH] "/users/51"`, I have an idea of how to route it in routes.rb but I want the best approach and so far you have led me on the right path.

Comment: Add `resources :users` to `routes.rb`. You seem to have completely missunderstood though - you create the associations by updating the parent record (the user) not by sending a request to WritingTypesController or whatever. (Your naming is just overcomplicated and strange).

Comment: okay so the user record gets the data, where does it store? Im using devise for my users, so in routes I have a devise_for with path names. I was thinking about adding the `collection_check_boxes` to my `devise/registrations/edit` page the form: `<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put, multipart: true }, :validate => true) do |f| %>`.  When I update, in the edit page it doesn't save. The check boxes remain unchecked when I go back.

Comment: `okay so the user record gets the data, where does it store?` - ActiveRecord will automatically create/delete the association(s) by inserting/deleting rows in the join table. Please read the Rails guides article on associations.

Comment: `When I update, in the edit page it doesn't save.` - the most likely cause is that you have not added `:subject_ids` or whatever the param is called to the strong parameters. You can read how to do that in the Devise wiki or one of the gazillion questions here on SO (devise does it a bit differently than your average Rails controller).

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association

Comment: I got it to work now for the user seperate from devise for now.. I will figure out the strong parameter for `devise` thank you!